# Erro ao tentar executar os programas no Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando executar os programas do python no Pycharm, mas está aparecendo uma mensagem de erro, como faço para corrigir esse erro, alguém sabe? abaixo, segue print do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conheço duas formas que podem resolver seu problema:

i. Segundo botão, dentro do compilador e selecione "Run[nome do programa]"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ii. Clicando em Run e depois em Edit Configuration

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, clique em adicionar uma nova configuração (no símbolo de +) e selecione o arquivo em "Script Path)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!